# No-GUI tool to take screenshots of websites

Tags: web-browser, command-line, screenshot

I want to generate screenshots of a lot of webpages, and doing it manually would take too much time.

Is there a tool to which I can give a list of URLs (public websites) and it would take screenshots.

- Need to render non-trivial HTML/CSS/JavaScript, for instance [this page](https://tools.wmflabs.org/wikivoyage/w/poimap2.php?lat=42.333333&lon=12.283333&zoom=13&layer=O&lang=en&name=Fabrica_di_Roma).
- Usable from command-line, preferably with no GUI elements popping up.
- Free, preferably open source, preferably without having to register for third-party APIs
- Any OS is OK, Linux is best.

Comment: there is a website http://web-capture.net/ which do the job but not fully satisfies your reqs

Comment: It's possible to do this sort of thing with [Selenium Webdriver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/take-a-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver) but (A) it will cause the browser window to pop up briefly whilst it's running and (B) you'd need to write some code to control it, which could be a problem if you're not a programmer. However, this would mean that the screenshots would show you EXACTLY what the browser would render.

Comment: Any operating system preferences?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## [Sindreshorus's pageres](https://github.com/sindresorhus/pageres-cli)

#### Support multiple resolutions

[image]

#### CLI support

```
$ pageres <url> <resolution> ...

$ pageres todomvc.com 1024x768 1366x768 # 2 screenshots
$ pageres todomvc.com yeoman.io 1024x768 # 2 screenshots
$ pageres todomvc.com yeoman.io 1024x768 1366x768 # 4 screenshots
```

#### Free and open-source

#### Support complex webpage:

```
$ pageres "https://tools.wmflabs.org/wikivoyage/w/poimap2.php?lat=42.333333&lon=12.283333&zoom=13&layer=O&lang=en&name=Fabrica_di_Roma" 1680x1080

      √ Generated 1 screenshot from 1 url and 1 resolution
```

[image]

Rendition is powered by [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).

Answer (score 6):

I know about a bunch of tools which claim to be able to do that. Out of curiosity I just tried all of them. I've listed the IMHO best working tools first, but YMMV:

## gnome-web-photo

[gnome-web-photo](https://launchpad.net/gnome-web-photo) as available in at least Debian and Ubuntu works fine and seems to be purely command-line driven despite having "gnome" in its name.

You need to pass `--mode=photo` explicitly, it doesn't seem to be the default.

Works fine for my own home page, but doesn't render the given example page in a usable way (1024x8 pixels).

## shutter

The perl-written [Shutter](http://shutter-project.org/) is a GUI program which by default waits in your system tray for screenshot requests. But you can also use it from the command-line.

When being used from the command-line, it still open a bunch of windows,  including a shortly flickering result window, even if you pass `-e` on the command-line which means to exit after the screenshot has been taken.

It seems to use gnome-web-photo as a back-end, at least gnome-web-photo is a optional dependency of shutter's Debian package. The result also looks the same as with gnome-web-photo.

Unfortunately shutter uses quite a lot of memory when being used as system tray application and has quite some seconds start-up time, both, in command-line mode as well as in system tray mode.

## webkit-image

Debian (and probably also derivatives like Ubuntu and Linux Mint) contain the two packages [webkit-image-gtk](https://packages.debian.org/stable/webkit-image-gtk) and [webkit-image-qt](https://packages.debian.org/stable/webkit-image-qt) which take a screenshot of a webpage by giving a URL as parameter.

Its upstream project [seems to be part of the OpenStreetMap editor Josm](http://svn.openstreetmap.org/applications/editors/josm/webgrabber/), but there's more information about the tool in Debian's package than ob that web page.

I just gave them a short try in Debian Unstable, but result was rather disappointing: webkit-image-qt generated a very tall and very narrow, unreadable image (195x11649 pixels) from my homepage and bailed out on the given example page without any image. And webkit-image-gtk resulted in a completely unusable image with just 1x8 pixels for both web pages. :-(

Comment: Thanks! Does the result of `shutter` look good for the example page?

Comment: Same as with gnome-web-photo. I though didn't check if it uses an alternative way to get the screenshot if gnome-web-photo is not installed.

Answer (score 2):

Not Fully Match Your Requirements

## [webpage thumbnailer](http://www.webpagethumbnailer.com/)

Windows Desktop Application that helps you convert MHTML and HTML to images in batch, capture full length website screenshots, generate thumbnail image previews of web pages. Supports JPG, GIF, PNG, BMP and TIF image formats.

> Key Features

Convert MHTML and HTML files to images in batch.

Capture websites screenshots.

Generate thumbnails of webpages.

Make schedule to take websites screenshots automatically.

Works in background, web page(s) doesn't need to be displayed or kept active to capture.

Works in multi threaded batch mode, which enables to capture multiple web pages at a time.

Supports JPG, GIF, PNG, BMP and TIF image formats.

Supports JPEG quality (compression) percent.

Supports capturing sites with flash content.

Supports delayed snapshots of websites.

Options to disable java, activex, scripts on the web page.

15 days free trial, $24.95 afterwards.

[image]

[image]

[image]